# Filter Websites via Squid

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, security, proxy, squid

I would like to install Squid to block all the websites and only allow a few websites (whitelist). Each department will have different rules.

For example on the Sales department - all the websites will be blocked and only allow a few whitelist websites. On the Customer Services department, all the websites will be open but facebook and youtube will be blocked.

If I use Squid, is it possible in this situation to filter on each department? I've done the network design that I am planning to setup. I could install Squid or pfsense for squid use on VM3 on the ESXi server.

[image]

PS: I do not have VLAN on switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I use Squid, is it possible in this situation to filter on each department?

There are a couple methods.  Setup and require [proxy authentication](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Authentication), possibly using Kerberos or NTLM if you have a Windows Domain.  With proxy authentication you can use the authenticated user in ACLs.

The other option is to make sure all the clients in a particular group are assigned an IP within a specific range.  That way you can build ACLs based on the source IP.

See the Squid ACL FAQ for details and other possibilities.

- http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl

Comment: PS You might want to also look at adding the SquidGuard plugin.  It may make this a bit easier.

Comment: Thanks Zoredache. I will look into this. I realise I have to change the proxy setting on the browser on each workstations. That is might be a bit of pain.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create VLAN on switch, as if you dont,then the clients will be able to acces the gateway themselves and use internet without any restrictions.
Create on VLAN, in which only clients have access, and the other VLAN, which has access to gateway as well (which will be squid server).

And for squid server, i would recommend you to use dansguarian or squidguard for blocking or whistling websites.

Comment: I do not have VLAN on switch

Comment: is it a managed switch?